# windows batch .bat exiting before all commands executed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've a `.bat` file which a sequence of instructions, however at some point the instructions are not runned anymore. This is a section of the latest run command:

```
gem update --system
gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundle
gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler
bundle install
echo EVERYTHING OK
echo Configuring DB
```

The first command shows this and then the program is exited:

```
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

So I tried to run all those commands in a single one:

```
gem update --system & gem .....  & bundle install & echo THIS IS PRINTED OK
echo THIS IS NOT PRINTED
```

I can't understand why the last echo is not getting printed, but all the commands wiht an `&` works.

Comment: `gem` is a batch file either, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a batch file includes a command that is another batch file, the batch processor interprets that as an instruction to replace the current batch file with the specified one.  This behaviour comes to us from the dark days of MS-DOS, but has been retained for backwards compatibility.  (Which is probably also the only reason the batch processor still exists!)

If you want to run the other batch file *and then continue*, you must use the `call` command, e.g.,

```
call gem update
```

For *best* results, to ensure that no state leaks up from the batch file you're calling, run it in a child process:

```
cmd /c gem update
```

(It is rather unfortunate, IMO, that `gem` is a batch file rather than a proper executable.)

Answer (score 1):

Each time a command is executed in batch file, it passes control of the execution flow to the child process.

To avoid this, we need to prefix `CALL` before each command:

```
call gem update --system
call gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundle
call gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler
call bundle install

echo EVERYTHING OK
echo Configuring DB
```

Comment: You do not need a CALL in front of the ECHO statements.

Comment: You have the correct solution but the wrong explanation.  When you run a normal executable from a batch file the command interpreter creates a child process to run it and behaves as you would expect; there is no need for `call` in that case.  The reason you need `call` when running another batch file is precisely that there *is* no child process in that case.  The command interpreter runs the batch file itself, without passing the job to a child process.  By default it doesn't return to the original batch file (for historical reasons) and you need `call` to tell it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the command is exiting before the echo is executed. 
Try to use the `CALL` command in front of each command in the script.